# Get loop data of angular 6 html table on seprate button click

Tags: checkbox, html-table, angular6

I am working on new angular 6 application and i am new to angular 6.

I have to implement the new function like.i am having one html table with multiple column some of them have checkbox along with id in hiddenfield. Now i have one button which is outside html table.

Now on the hutton click i have to get selected rows of one checkbox column. I have tried to search same on google but not getting any good solution for this.

Can anyone help to achive these functionality.

Thanks in advance.
Omkar

Comment: what is the issue you are facing, which part you are getting issue ?

Comment: Hello Krishna, As mention i am new to angular 6 i wabt know how can get rowid or hidden field value of the row where i have selected checkbox from specific colum. So basically when user click on button i want to fetch rows using each function fot furthur process.

Comment: <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of mf.data; let i = index;">
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="" [checked]="item.checked"></td>

      <td>{{item.id}}</td>
      <td>{{item.name}}</td>
      <td>{{item.email}}</td>
      <td>{{item.age}}</td>
      <td>{{item.city | uppercase}}</td>
      <td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

Answer (score 0):

```
you can do this stuff without the need of button by following :

checkbox :
    <input type='checkbox' ng-repeat="fruit in fruits"
      ng-checked="checkedFruits.indexOf(fruit) != -1" ng-click="toggleCheck(fruit)">

the function get called : 
    function SomeCtrl ($scope) {
        $scope.fruits = ["apple, orange, pear, naartjie"];
        $scope.checkedFruits = [];
    $scope.toggleCheck = function (fruit) {
        if ($scope.checkedFruits.indexOf(fruit) === -1) {
            $scope.checkedFruits.push(fruit);
        } else {
            $scope.checkedFruits.splice($scope.checkedFruits.indexOf(fruit), 1);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I am using angular 6 is scope used in angular 6? I am not sure. Can you please share code for each row.